# JavaScript replace not removing carriage return

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have a json object that's generated from a csv file:

```
{"FID":["FID"],"the_geom":["the_geom"],"X":["X"],"Y":["Y"],"ROW":["ROW"],"COL":["COL"],"EMH":["EMH"],"B":["B_SURF","B_SUB1","B_SUB2"],"BP_CA":["BP_CA_SUR","BP_CA_SUB1","BP_CA_SUB2"],"BP_K":["BP_K_SURF","BP_K_SUB1","BP_K_SUB2"],"BP_MG"["BP_MG_SUR","BP_MG_SUB1","BP_MG_SUB2"],"BP_NA":["BP_NA_SUR","BP_NA_SUB1","BP_NA_SUB2"],"CA"["CA_SURF","CA_SUB1","CA_SUB2"],"CAMG":["CAMG_SURF","CAMG_SUB1","CAMG_SUB2"],"CEC"["CEC_SURF","CEC_SUB1","CEC_SUB2"],"CLAY":["CLAY_SURF","CLAY_SUB1","CLAY_SUB2"],"CU"["CU_SURF","CU_SUB1","CU_SUB2"],"DPRR_SUMM":["DPRR_SUMM"],"DRAIN_SUMM"["DRAIN_SUMM"],"FE":["FE_SURF","FE_SUB1","FE_SUB2"],"K"["K_SURF","K_SUB1","K_SUB2"],"KMG":["KMG_SURF","KMG_SUB1","KMG_SUB2"],"MG"["MG_SURF","MG_SUB1","MG_SUB2"],"MN":["MN_SURF","MN_SUB1","MN_SUB2"],"NA":["NA_SURF","NA_SUB1","NA_SUB2"],"OM":["OM_SURF","OM_SUB1","OM_SUB2"],"P"["P_SURF","P_SUB1","P_SUB2"],"PAVL"["PAVL_SURF","PAVL_SUB1","PAVL_SUB2"],"PAW24_SUMM":["PAW24_SUMM"],"PAW30_SUMM"["PAW30_SUMM"],"PAW36_SUMM":["PAW36_SUMM"],"PAW42_SUMM":["PAW42_SUMM"],"PAW48_SUMM":["PAW48_SUMM"],"PH":["PH_SURF","PH_SUB1","PH_SUB2"],"RZFC_SUMM":["RZFC_SUMM"],"RZKUSAT_SU"["RZKUSAT_SU"],"RZPAW_SUMM":["RZPAW_SUMM"],"RZPWP_SUMM"["RZPWP_SUMM"],"RZSAT_SUMM":["RZSAT_SUMM"],"S":["S_SURF","S_SUB1","S_SUB2"],"SAND":["SAND_SURF","SAND_SUB1","SAND_SUB2"],"TEX"["TEX_SURF","TEX_SUB1","TEX_SUB2"],"THICK"["THICK_SURF","THICK_SUB1","THICK_SUB2"],"TIP":["TIP_SURF","TIP_SUB1","TIP_SUB2"],"ZN":["ZN_SURF","ZN_SUB1","ZN_SUB2"],"EMV"["EMV"],"ASP":["ASP"],"DEM":["DEM"],"SLOPE\r":["SLOPE\r"]}
```

At the very end, the slope object has a carriage return in the name (it was carried over from the csv conversion)

I need to remove that carriage return from the object, as it messes up some other scripts that parse the object.

I tried testing it by doing:

```
console.log("Without carrage return: " + JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace(/[\n\r]/g, ''));
```

But when I print it, it still contains the carriage return.

I'm probably doing something stupid here, I'm just so tired I'm not noticing it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Try `replace(/\\r/g, '')`.

Comment: It might be that's not really a carriage return but rather the string `\r`.

Comment: BTW the JSON string listed above is invalid.

Comment: @MinusFour: `JSON.stringify()` escapes control characters to their escape sequence representation. If the input contained the string `\r`, the JSON would contain `\\r` and `.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g, '')` wouldn't have matched it.

Comment: Well, I wasn't fully right. `.replace(/[\\r\\n]/g, '')` would have matched it because it matches every backslash and also the letters r and n. But `.replace(/\\r/g, '')` would keep one backslash in the string.

Comment: @MaxZoom I ran it through a lint, and I see what you mean. My actual string it fine, so I think I accidentally deleted some characters when adding it to the question

Comment: Ah, OK then. I have tried to use it and noticed some issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is a little bit broken. Since \ is also a special character you need to defferentiate that as well.

Try doing this instead:

```
console.log("Without carrage return: " + JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace(/[\\n\\r]/g, ''));
```

Your regex is matching the \r character as a whole but since you are converting everything to a string you end up having to match for the characters '\' and 'r'.

Comment: The regex is correct but the explanation is not. You not escaping the special character `\\` because it is required for a carriage return, but to match the carriage return string representation (not the carriage return itself). See this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/nE1zM9/1) for true CR match illustration.

Answer (score 2):

In regular expressions `\r` and `\n` match carriage return and new line, but `JSON.stringify()` transforms the carriage return into `'\r'`.

So you just need to use `\\r` instead of `\r`:

```
console.log("Without carrage return: " + JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace(/\\n|\\r/g, ''));
```

EDIT: `/[\\n\\r]/g` would have matched every backslash and every letter r and n in the string and not only the sequence \r. `/\\n|\\r/g` works better.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the \r in the csv is literally a backslash and a r?

```
 console.log( JSON.stringify(jsonObject).replace("\\r", "") )
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't catch that... I guess that's what happens when you only get 5 hours of sleep due to deadlines :)

Comment: Does it only remove first `\r` occurrence?

Comment: Actually this is partially incorrect, as @MaxZoom asked, it does indeed only remove the first occurrence.